# Pascal Pointers changing their pointing value

Tags: delphi, pointers, pascal

I'm relative new to Pascal and currently working with pointers.
I've got 2 records, one of them contains 2 pointers to the other record type.

```
type
  WaypointRef = ^Waypoint;

  PathRef = ^Path;

  Waypoint = record
    id: integer;
    Name: string;
    pathRefs: array of PathRef;
  end;

  Path = record
    distance: integer;
    WaypointRefA, WaypointRefB: WaypointRef;
  end;
```

All waypoints are saved in an array.
Now, when I try to read out the value of a path I get mysterious results:

```
writeln(waypoints[0].pathRefs[0]^.distance);
writeln(waypoints[1].pathRefs[0]^.distance);
```

Both should print the same values but they don't.
However, the more mysterious thing is that even if I try the following:

```
writeln(waypoints[0].pathRefs[0]^.distance);
writeln(waypoints[0].pathRefs[0]^.distance);
writeln(waypoints[0].pathRefs[0]^.distance);
```

I get 2 different values. (The right one - 173 - first and then 2 all times afterwards.)

```
waypoints[0].pathRefs[0]^
```

always points to the same address and thus I'm very confused. I hope someone knows the issue.

EDIT: 2 seems to be the default value as it also returns 2 if I don't save any value to "distance" at the path creation.

EDIT2: Here the code of the waypoint and path-creation. I think there must be an failure. I now it might be confusing design because of the procedures inside the procedures. I'm just experimenting.

```
procedure buildWaypoint(Name: string);

  procedure addWaypoint(w: Waypoint);
  var
    lngth: integer;
  begin
    lngth := Length(waypoints);
    SetLength(waypoints, lngth + 1);
    waypoints[lngth] := w;
  end;

var
  w: Waypoint;
begin
  w.id := id;
  id := id + 1;

  w.Name := Name;
  addWaypoint(w);
end;

procedure buildPath(waypointRefA, waypointRefB: WaypointRef; distance: integer);

  procedure addPath(pRef: PathRef);

    procedure addPathToWaypoint(pRef: PathRef; wRef: WaypointRef);
    var
      lngth: integer;
    begin
      lngth := length(wRef^.pathRefs);
      SetLength(wRef^.pathRefs, lngth + 1);
      wRef^.pathRefs[lngth] := pRef;
    end;

  begin
    addPathToWaypoint(pRef, pRef^.WaypointRefA);
    addPathToWaypoint(pRef, pRef^.WaypointRefB);
  end;

var
  p: path;
begin
  p.distance := distance;
  p.WaypointRefA := waypointRefA;
  p.WaypointRefB := waypointRefB;

  addPath(@p);
end;
```

Comment: Can you show how you set the pathRefs array?

Comment: Why are you using pointers if you're also using an array?

Comment: Please show a complete test so your problems can be reproduced. @No'amNewman, pointers are here so that the records can crossreference data without duplicating.

Comment: @LURD Thanks for you fast reply. I added the code which creates the records. I think in there must be an error.

Comment: @Endzeit: where are you creating the pointers? There's no 'new' in your example.

Comment: @No'amNewman I create a path by calling buildPath() whos pointer is passed to addPath() and then written into the array of the desired Waypoints. Well, atleast that was the plan.

Comment: I think the problem is with how you are treating your arrays. You see dynamic arrays are zero-based which means that first item has an index 0. That means that when you want to acces last array item its index will always be one less than the number of items in array. So instead of "waypoints[lngth] := w;" use "waypoints[lngth-1] := w;" Also I strongly recomend you turn on the Rage Checkin in Project Options.

Comment: Is `waypoints` an `array of Waypoint` or an `array of WaypointRef`? If the latter, you should be doing `writeln(waypoints[0]^.pathRefs[0]^.distance);` instead of `writeln(waypoints[0].pathRefs[0]^.distance);`.

Comment: @SilverWarior While it's a good idea to always compile with range-checking on, that's not the problem here. The code is a little confusing because in `wRef^.pathRefs[lngth] := pRef;` the variable `lngth` actually refers to the _old_ length. The previous line did SetLength to `lngth + 1`. So the memory access is within range. The issue is as per my answer. I'll add a simple console app to demonstrate.

Comment: @AndriyM Technically yes. It would be more precise to explicitly dereference the pointers. But there are a few situations where explicit dereferencing is optional and compiled code will be identical with or without the caret `^`.

Comment: @CraigYoung: Ah yes, I think I remember now, something to do with extended syntax probably. I'll look it up to refresh my memory, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 things that could cause this kind of unexpected behaviour:

1. If you have array-type properties for `waypoints[0]` and `pathRefs[0]` backed by getter methods: then there could be the possibility of those methods having side-effects which would cause the problem. (*Obviously that's not the case here*).
2. If your pointers are referecing "invalid memory" locations: then memory overwrites by other code can cause the value to change. (*And this is your problem*.)

The path that you're adding is declared on the stack:

```
var
  p: path;  //<-- Stack variable
begin
  ...    
  addPath(@p);
end; //<-- When you leave the method the stack variable is no longer valid.
```

- As a result of this code, your `wRef^.pathRefs[??]` points to an address higher up on the call stack.
- As you call other methods, that same memory gets used for other purposes.
- And the values can change.

You need to ensure that you point to memory on the heap. You do this by using dynamic memory allocation routines: `New`, `Dispose`, `GetMem`, `FreeMem`.

**EDIT**

[Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Dynamic_Memory_Allocation_Routines) about dynamic memory allocation routines.

Example of how you could change your code:

```
procedure addPathToWaypoint(pRef: PathRef; wRef: WaypointRef);
var
  lngth: integer;
  LpRefOnHeap: PathRef;
begin
  lngth := length(wRef^.pathRefs);
  SetLength(wRef^.pathRefs, lngth + 1);
  New(LpRefOnHeap); //Allocate heap memory
  LpRefOnHeap^ := pRef^; //Copy data pointed to by pRef to heap
  wRef^.pathRefs[lngth] := LpRefOnHeap; //Hold reference to an address that won't
                                        //become invalid when stack unwinds.
end;
```

**NOTE**: You'll have to figure out where and when to dispose of the dynamically allocated memory.

---

**EDIT2**  Add a simple console app to demonstrate the problem.

```
program InvalidUseOfStackVar;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  PData = ^TData;
  TData = record
    Value: Integer;
  end;

var
  GData: PData;

procedure SetData;
var
  LData: TData; //Stack variable will no longer be valid when routine exits.
begin
  LData.Value := 42; //The initial value pointed to by GData
  GData := @LData; //The global var will continue to point to invalid memory after exit.
end;

procedure ChangeStack;
var
  //This is written to have the same stack layout as the previous routine.
  LData: TData;
begin
  LData.Value := 777; //This unintentionally changes data pointed to by the global var
end;

begin
  SetData;                //Sets GData, but GData points to an address on the call stack
  Writeln(GData^.Value);  //Writes 42 because that's what was on the stack at the time of the method call.
  ChangeStack;            //Updates the stack variable to a different value
  Writeln(GData^.Value);  //Now writes 777 because GData points to the same location in memory, but the
                          //data at that location was changed.
  Writeln(GData^.Value);  //Note: calling the Writeln method above also changes the stack.
                          //The only difference is that it is less predictable for us to determine
                          //how the stack will be changed.
  Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score -1):

You are passing wayPointRefA and wayPointRefB to buildPath procedure. That procedure is supposed to create a path between these 2 waypoints and then add it to the array of paths of both of those waypoints. All of your business logic is fine. 
Here lies the problem. You haven't thought about lifetimes. Your wayPointA and wayPointB will hold a pointer to P and P exists on the stack frame of buildPath procedure, which means that immediately after you actually create path P that represents a path between waypointA and wayPointB and add pointer to P in the array of paths of both of those waypoints, P goes out of scope and pointer to P becomes a dangling pointer. I suppose that your program doesn't crash because when you call another procedure or function your program again owns that part of memory where P used to live but now that part of memory is used for something completely different. P is no longer stored there. That's why you get nonsense values when you try to access fields of pathrefs.

Unfortunately, the Pascal compiler accepts this crap code. Unfortunately, there is no concept of owning vs borrowing memory in Pascal, neither there are lifetime annotations. In Rust @P (or rather &P) would mean that you are borrowing the data and you would have to specify lifetime annotations. Since P doesn't live long enough your code wouldn't compile. You could also have waypoints own the path data and then your code wouldn't compile because @P (&P in Rust) would not be an owned type. 
 If you were writing the program in Rust, you would wrap P in a reference counter (Rc) because you have 2 waypoints that own the same path data.

In Pascal you can put path on the heap by using the new keyword (the same keyword that many other languages use). Then, waypoints will not have a dangling pointer. Still, keep in mind that you are circulary referencing waypoints and paths, so you need to be very careful with memory management. If you can, it is best to avoid a scenario where paths and waypoints are circulary referencing each other.